# Get height of a division tag in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My division tag with id "container" has the following style

```
<style>
#container {
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

I am retrieving the height and width as follows

```
var WIDTH = $("#container").width();
var HEIGHT = $("#container").height();
```

this height and width is required by me to set up my view in WEBGL.

Am getting the width correct but `height()` returns `0`. Initially I thought am not populating my division tag with any data before I get height and width, may be that's the reason why `height()` returns `0` but if that is the case how am I getting `width()` correct?

If I set my width and height in terms of pixels they work fine, but the problem is I want to be accurate when the webpage is being viewed on different screens.

Comment: Please post a [*complete* example replicating the problem](http://sscce.org) in the question. (You might *also* include a link to a http://jsbin.com / http://jsfiddle.net / http://codepen.io, as an addition.)

Comment: off-topic  - but use outerWidth and outerHEight instead

Comment: What is the height of your `#container` when you inspect it in some developer tool ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to set the height of its parent element. If this is the only element, consider adding `body, html {height: 100%}` to your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `html,body{height: 100%;}` then only it works. Otherwise you could apply your div to be position absolute then only works.

```
#container {
background: #000;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
}
```

And to place where the div is wrap it with a div and apply position to relative.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include or write something into the div. When there is no content in the div how can it give the height of the div?

Try out the demo http://jsfiddle.net/T8D7V/

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var w=$('#container').css('width');
      var h=$('#container').css('height');
      alert("  height"+h+"  width"+w);     
   });
```

I hope you wanted to achieve this....

Answer (score 0):

The  is calculated with respect to the height of the containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly, the value computes to auto.

so if the containing block of #container did not has an explicit height.

the height of #container will be the height of its content

if the the containing block of #container is set explicit such as 100px

the height of `#container` will calculate with the value (100px in this example)

```
http://jsfiddle.net/PL595/ i have some example here
```

mdn : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height

Answer (score -1):

it should be:

```
var WIDTH = $("#container").css('width').replace('px','');
var HEIGHT = $("#container").css('height').replace('px','');
```

Or

```
var WIDTH = document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth;
var HEIGHT = document.getElementById('container').offsetHeight;
```

Comment: use parseInt instead. no need for remove PX,EM etc... `parseInt('123BlaBla') //123`

Comment: I never have any problems calculating the height of an element by just using `$(element).height();`  This always returns the height of the element for me... strange.

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as `.offset().width` and `.offset().height`, this will not work. You can only do `.offset().top` and `.offset().left`  The offset returns the position of an element `x` and `y`, not the width/height.

Comment: sorry, I have some confusion.